# Github: What's the best way to maintain a stable project?

Tags: github

Is there a preferred way to set up projects or branches on github, so there's always a stable branch available for people to download? How do you guys set up your projects?

Here's an example: right now I have a "stable" branch(master) and then an "edge" branch(for development only). When I am ready to release a new version to the public, I will merge my edge branch onto the stable one. Is that a recommended approach? Thanks!

Comment: It sounds like you've already got the right approach. Both branches will be available on github but as long as you have something in the readme on the subject folks will know that only the master branch is stable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sounds like a fine (and normal) approach. What you can do is to have multiple development branches, for each feature or bug fix your are working on. This allows you to switch between the branches depending on what you want to work on today. But if you are a lone developer on your project, that may just be overkill.

Just a late update to my answer, I found this article and it looks like a very good approach to version control using git: http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/
And incidentally this is very close to the way we use version control at work.

However this is probably most relevant for projects with multiple people.

Comment: Cool, thanks for the feedback, guys! I always like to hear different perspectives when it comes to development approaches.